# How to pass each value of an array to a method and get back all the result in another array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops

So i have an array of Json objects and i will like to pass each values of this object to a method one by one and get all the value together as result in an array.  the size of the array of objects is dynamic.

let's say i have:

```
const output = [
    {
      user: '123456'
    },
   
    { 
      user: '123456'
    },
   
    {
      user: '123456'
    }
]
```

i want to pass the value of `user` to the method

I tried using a for loop, but it only return one value instead of all. i tried:

```
for(var car of output) {
    client.getUserInfo(${car.user}).then((contact) => {
       dave.push(contact); 
       console.log(dave);
}
```

what i got was :

```
[
    {user info} 
]
```

i was expecting to get:

```
[
    {user info},
    {user info},
    {user info}
]
```

Comment: `dave.push(contact); `... what is `dave`? `Const` with a capital `C`? `for(var car of output)` ... `output`? Where is `output`? `{user info},` what is `user info` ?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: sorry typo errors, user info is ther result from the method   **getUserInfo**.

Comment: You mean something like `const dave = output.map(({user}) => client.getUserInfo(user))` assuming getUserInfo is not async

Comment: yes. let me try it out. @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean something like this, assuming getUserInfo is not async

```js
const client1 = {
  getUserInfo: (user) => `user: ${user}`
}

const dave1 = output.map(({user} ) => client1.getUserInfo(user))
console.log(dave1)

// or 

const client2 = {
  getUserInfo: (obj) => `user: ${obj.user}`
};
const dave2 = output.map(client2.getUserInfo)

console.log(dave2)
```

```html
<script>
  const output = [{
      user: '123456'
    },

    {
      user: '123456'
    },
    {
      user: '123456'
    }
  ]
</script>
```